# How to map entity associations with doctrine 2 to retrieve specific data?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, model-associations

**Introduction**:

The title of the question is a bit generic because I was not able to make a more specific one, but now I will try to give a better description of my problem.
It's my first big project with Symfony (>=3.*) and Doctrine ORM (>=2.5) and I hope to get some tips about what to keep in mind to improve my understanding about modelling entity associations.

**Minimized Use Case** (ps: `CodeStyled` words are Doctrine Entities):

- I have the `AccountType` entity where are defined 4 account types.
- A `User` can register his credentials and must choose one `AccountType`.
- I have 5 profile types in the relative entities `ProfileOne`, `ProfileTwo`, `ProfileThree`, `ProfileFour`, `ProfileFive`.
- The `User` with `AccountType:A` can create only 1 `ProfileOne` and only 1 `ProfileTwo`.
- The `User` with `AccountType:B` can create unlimited `ProfileOne` and `ProfileTwo`.
- The `User` with `AccountType:C` can create unlimited `ProfileFour`.
- The `User` with `AccountType:D` can create only 1 `ProfileFive`.

**Actual Entity Associations**:

- `User` have a unidirectional `OneToOne` with `AccountType`.

**The Question (UPDATED)**:

I'm forced to manage the logic outside (es: in a repository) or exist a way to map entities to retrieve the right data based on the `AccountType` (as showed in the use-case)?

Maybe I've to create a `ProfileAccountA`, `ProfileAccountB`, `ProfileAccountC` and a `ProfileAccountD`, where to store the relative associations based on the `AccountType` to then be able to have something like `$profile = $user->getProfile()` where inside the function `getProfile()` I manage the logic to returns the right data (like in a Factory class)? If Yes, is this a common and valid approach or there are better alternatives for this use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class for each account type (eg.: AccountTypeA, AccountTypeB, etc.). The properties, associations, and rules that tell which and how many profiles a `User` can have should be encapsulated in those classes.

Your associations will look like this: *`User` has an (oneToOne) `Account` that has one or more (oneToMany) `Profile`*

You will probably want an `AccountInterface`:

```
interface AccountInterface
{
    public function getProfiles(): Collection;
}
```

An example of an Account class. It's better naming them accordingly to their nature (FreeAccount, MasterAccount...):

```
class MasterAccount implements AccountInterface
{
    private $masterProfile;
    private $expirationDate;
    private $anotherAccountRelatedProperty;

    public function getProfiles(): Collection
    {
         return new ArrayCollection([$this->masterProfile]);
    }
}
```

Any property, association, or behavior related to the account should live in these classes.

In order to get the `User` profiles it should delegate to the account:

```
//User class

private $account;

public function getProfiles(): Collection
{
    return $this->account->getProfiles();
}
```

This is a decent OOP approach to be used as guideline in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay but I was in travel. What you've described was also my first thought as you saw in my question. About the `getProfile()` method was only an example and maybe was better to name `getData()` for this case (since some account type is associated to one or more collection and not to only a single profile of one type). Using this approach, do you think I should associate all the `ProfileAccount*` classes to the `AccountType` or elsewhere?

Comment: @RocketOne Using this approach you won't have the `AccountType` class. `ProfileAccount*` would be associated to the `User`, It's better to name them `Account*` instead of `ProfileAccount*`. So it will look like:  `User` has an `Account*` that has one or more `Profile*`.  `getData()` is usually a bad name for functions since it's too generic and not meaningful. Even if some of your `Account*` is associated to a single `Profile*` it should return a collection to conform to the interface, add a return type (`Collection` or `array`) if using PHP7.0+.

Comment: Hi Renan, I've got your point but the `AccountType` entity is mandatory because it contains also other associations and properties that don't belongs to `User` (my example is minimized respect to the reality). Can you update your answer with a more detailed example considering this requirement?

Comment: @RocketOne Sure, I've updated my answer. Remember that what is most important here is the suggested approach, you should adapt the code to your needs, maybe using inheritance for the account classes for example.

Comment: Thanks again Renan! I accepted your answer for your effort and in the next days I will play with this to see how to adapt this approach or a similar one to mantain the AccountType entity. If not enough I will post a more specific question next time.

Comment: @RocketOne You are welcome. Keep in mind that using this approach you don't need the AccountType anymore. These other associations and properties you mentioned (related to the accounts) should be placed in the `Account*` classes, like in the `MasterAccount` of the example. Instead of having instances of your old `AccountType` class, it will become multiple classes like `FreeAccount`, `MasterAccount`, etc. with their own properties and behavior.